# how to compare the 2 arrays. 1'st array values which is enter by user and 2'nd are this winningPossibility

Tags: javascript

```
const winningPossibility = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [3,6,9],
    [1,5,9],
    [3,5,7]
]

function checkWin(win){
   var isEqual = win.every((value) => value === winningPossibility[[0]])
   console.log(isEqual)
}
```

Please can you compare this both array I need this thing in my Tic-toe-tac game

Comment: I only see 1 array

Comment: What is expected as a result of such a comparison?

Comment: If it's to find out whether given array (e.g. `[1,5,9]`) is present in exactly the same order in `winningPossibility`, you may use `.some()` : `checkWin = win => winningPossibility.some(a => a.every((n,i) => win[i] == n))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
function checkWin(win){
   return !!winningPossibility.find(possibility => possibility.every(num => win.includes(num)))
}
```